# Creating Task via Powershell as System32

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, task, scheduler

I want to create a Task via Powershell, but i get this Error:

Register-ScheduledTask : Access Denied
In C:\Users\4TL4S\Documents\Coding\Bot_Dev\juri_exc\ui\setup_bot_task.ps1:8 Zeichen:1

- Register-ScheduledTask "Bot_Activation" -InputObject $Task
- 
- CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask)
  [Register-ScheduledTask], CimException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Register-ScheduledTask

I think it has todo with that "Administrator" hasnt got enough rights...How could i fix this? Is it possible to create Task as System32?

This is the Script:

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "cmd.exe"
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At "0am" -DaysOfWeek 1 -Weekly
$Principle = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal "Administrator" -RunLevel Highest
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Principal $Principle -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings
Register-ScheduledTask "Bot_Activation" -InputObject $Task
```

This is the Code which calls the Script:

```
subprocess.Popen([r'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe',
                         '-ExecutionPolicy',
                         'Unrestricted',
                         './setup_bot_task.ps1'], cwd=os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run this is an elevated session using the "Run as adminstrator" option.

You can use `Start-Process` with the parameter `-Verb` and argument `runas`. See this test

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList @'
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "cmd.exe"
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At "0am" -DaysOfWeek 1 -Weekly
$Principle = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal "Administrator" -RunLevel Highest
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Principal $Principle -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings
Register-ScheduledTask "Bot_Activation" -InputObject $Task 
'@ -Verb runas
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass this as a Parameter? because this script is being called by a Python Script

Comment: I edited the Post with the Code which calls the PS1 Script

Comment: How do you normally elevate in python?

Comment: I honestly dont know there is a shell=False parameter of POpen but it doesnt really say if this elevates the privliges

Comment: I found win32api.ShellExecute but i didnt quite understand yet how to use it

Comment: Your Script Solved my Problem :) I mean it does open a Powershell Window but that doesnt really matter :)